# Matlab: Write the log likelihood function, then differentiate and solve it in MUPAD

Tags: matlab

I have tried to search but I cannot find anything relevant.

The log likelihood equation is:

```
f= -n/2*log(2*pi)-n/2*log(sig2)-1/(2*sig2)*(y-XB)'(y-XB)
```

e.g. X is a matrix; B is a vector

How could I get the following two equations?

```
1.df/dB=-((sig2)^-1)*[-X'y+X'XB]

2.set df/dB=0, then B=((X'X)^-1)X'y
```

Thanks a million.

Comment: Search for Matrix Calculus and take a look at the rules of differentiation when dealing with functions whose inputs are matrices: http://www.atmos.washington.edu/~dennis/MatrixCalculus.pdf .  No need to use MATLAB.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But can it done in the Matlab(MuPAD)? I tried to change the matrix notation to summation notation. I don't know why MuPAD show me this kind of results: discount(..........,z,undefiend)